# Is there any guide on how to run in Terraform code Run HashiCorp's Vault in ECS using Fargate?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, hashicorp-vault

I am using Terraform and would like to get a better understading of how to implemtnt Hashicorp vault with AWS ECS fargate.

How this should be configured?

Thanks!

I have tried to implement the task defintion like this, but not sure if it will work or/and how to define the service

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_first_vault" {
  family                   = "my-first-task" # Naming our first task
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "my-first-vault",
      "image": "vault:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8200,
          "hostPort": 8200
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "VAULT_ADDR",
          "value": "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
        },
        {
          "name": "VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG",
          "value": "{ \"backend\": {\"file\": {\"path\": \"/vault/file\"}}, \"default_lease_ttl\": \"168h\", \"max_lease_ttl\": \"720h\", \"listener\": [{ \"tcp\": { \"address\": \"0.0.0.0:8200\", \"tls_disable\": true }}] }"
        }
      ],
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] # Stating that we are using ECS Fargate
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"    # Using awsvpc as our network mode as this is required for Fargate
  memory                   = 512         # Specifying the memory our container requires
  cpu                      = 256         # Specifying the CPU our container requires
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @MarkoE, not yet...
Actually,  I am trying to deploy vault by referencing the following Medium guide [link] (https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-deploy-a-dockerised-node-js-application-on-aws-ecs-with-terraform-3e6bceb48785)

Comment: So the apply worked?

Comment: @MarkoE, Yeah, the apply worked.
I think that I am missing actually, the script to unseal the vault..